# Executing conditions step-by-step in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I execute the first if condition, it does not check the inside if condition. Why is this so? I'm trying to put myself in a mind of a user. They might choose b1 and then choose b2 later on. Or they might choose b2 and then choose b1 later on. However, when I tried to choose b1 first and then b2 second, it goes automatically to the third if condition which is when they choose b2 first.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
  if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("b1"))
  {
     transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
     transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);

     if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("b2"))
     {
        transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        transform.GetChild(3).gameObject.SetActive(true);
      }
  }

  if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("b2"))
  {
     transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
     transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive(true);

     if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("b1"))
     {
         transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive(false);
         transform.GetChild(3).gameObject.SetActive(true);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I execute the first if condition, it does not check the inside if condition

Because thats impossible. You're saying 'If the tag is b1, and if the tag is b2'. The tag cannot be both, its either b1 or b2.

If the user chooses b2 at a later point, the method is called again and is executed from the top. It doesnt just continue where it left off last time.

If you want this behaviour you'll have to add extra logic, for example keep track which tags have been collided with in the past.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, is there any other workaround for this then? To get the desired result? Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate what the desired result is? I think you need to keep a list of all the objects the player has collided with, and test against that.

Comment: The results I'm trying to acquire is that:

If User choose b1, show sprite(1) user then choose b2, sprite(1) disappear and sprite(3) appear.

If user choose b2 first, show sprite(2), user then choose b1, sprite(2) disappear and sprite(3) appear.

Comment: You are already keeping track of it then! What you can do is when b2 is selected, see if sprite 1 is visible. In that case the user must have clicked b1 before.